# SpriteKit: Weird crash when preloading texture atlases

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, crash, preloading

I am currently working on a game for iOS using SpriteKit and I encountered a weird crash while implementing preloading of texture atlases. Here is a quick outline of what I got so far:

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsDrawCount = true
        skView.showsPhysics = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        // Setup scene
        let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        let MyAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas1")
        let MyAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas2")
        let MyAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas3")

        SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([MyAtlas1, MyAtlas2, MyAtlas3], withCompletionHandler: 
        {
            print("Everything loaded!")

            // Present scene
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        })
    }
    [...]
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var cam: SKCameraNode!
    var tilemap: Tilemap!
    var previousTime: CFTimeInterval = 0
    [...]

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        [...]

        // Setup camera
        self.cam = SKCameraNode()
        self.cam.setScale(self.camScaleFactor)
        self.camera = self.cam
        self.addChild(self.cam)

        [...]

        // Load Tilemap
        self.tilemap = Tilemap(mapName: "testlevel2")
        self.addChild(self.tilemap)

        // Setup UI
        [...]
    }

    [...]

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        if self.previousTime == 0 {
            self.previousTime = currentTime
        }

        let delta = currentTime - self.previousTime

        var p = self.cam.position
        p.x += 2.0 * CGFloat(delta)
        p.y += 1.5 * CGFloat(delta)
        self.cam.position = p

        // Update tilemap
        self.tilemap.update(delta)

        self.previousTime = currentTime
    }
}
```

The didMoveToView function is a bit lengthy, as it initializes a camera, a tilemap, UI stuff and some constraints. However, this compiles just fine. But when I run the game, it immediately crashes with the following fatal error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". As it turns out, that Optional Value is (randomly) either self.tilemap or self.cam and the error occurs in the update() function of GameScene on one of the following lines (also, randomly):

```
// here
var p = self.cam.position

// or here
self.tilemap.update(delta)
```

The debugger tells me that either self.tilemap or self.cam is nil. But I cannot figure why that is the case. It appears to me that the function didMoveToView gets executed when the scene is presented and then suddenly halfway through, the update function is called where self.tilemap or self.cam is still uninitialized.

When I change the viewDidLoad function of the GameViewController to this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsDrawCount = true
        skView.showsPhysics = false
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        // Setup scene
        let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        let MyAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas1")
        let MyAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas2")
        let MyAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MyAtlas3")

        SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([MyAtlas1, MyAtlas2, MyAtlas3], withCompletionHandler: 
        {
            print("Everything loaded!")                
        })

        // Present scene
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
    [...]
```

everything works perfectly. But that is obviously not the solution, because I want to preload everything *before* starting the scene. Also note: I am aware that the preloaded atlases get removed from memory right away, since I do not keep a strong reference to them. Anyhow, that code is really just for demonstration and testing.

So my question is: Has anybody ever had a similar issue or knows what is going on with that error? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you look on the console, it should tell you what the variable is that is nil so that you are not guessing.  Also, Why are you loading your atlases in the view controller?  Load them in the GameScene

Comment: I did not guess. As I said, it is randomly either self.tilemap or self.cam. What is the benefit of loading atlases in the GameScene instead of loading them in the ViewController?

Comment: Code readability, View controllers should not know anything about atlases,  the GameScene does,  so 6 months down the road, you pick this code back up, you are not wondering where you put those darn atlases.  And the code can't randomly go to update without finishing didMoveToView, they are on the same thread, so something else is going on in your code that we do not know about

Comment: Ok, then I need to look into it further. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

[image: attach image ho setup SKView for UIView]

You create app using template, it will create view as `SCNView`.
This `SCNView` collide with you desire to have on story board `SKView`.

1. Delete `SCNView` from you storyboard
2. `SKView` is not available as View option
3. Enter regular `UIView` to storyboard
4. On properties class, type `SKView`, it will accept even it is not on list
5. This will fix issue when you trying to create `SKView`

See attach image.